# 1140 Grid system - grids inside grids

Tags: html, grid

So i'm having difficulty understanding the [1140 grid system](http://cssgrid.net)

I've looked at the 1140 website for clues and tried finding websites built using this system.

I've setup a page but am unable to understand how grids are placed inside one another.

Has anyone built a site or know a site using the 1140 grid system or can help with understanding how it is setup.

Comment: what do you not understand? I'm not sure if 1140 allows nested grids at all, but other than that it's just container>row>span1-12, next_row>span1-12...

Comment: When nesting grids and scaling down to 'mobile' media query it adds a 20px left and right padding which doubles up when nesting grids.

Comment: correct. I commented this out in my css... See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I changed the 1140 CSS mobile version to:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px){  
    body         {/* font-size: 1em; */ -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}
    .row, body   {width: 100%; min-width: 0; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; margin-top: -1px;
.row .span1, .row .span2, .row .span2, .row .span3, .row .span4, .row .span5, .row .span6, .row .span7, .row .span8, .row .span9, .row .span10, .row .span11, .row .span12
                {width: auto; float: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; /*padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;*/}
    }
```

So yes, the 20px also bothered me :-).

I have acutally changed the grid quite a bit as I'm using it with Jquery Mobile, but the principle still remains and is very good.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so the main thing you've done (aside from the other changes to media queries/selectors) is remove the padding left and right? How do you solve the problem, when in mobile view everything is right upto the edge..

Comment: Jquery Mobile also adds 15px on both sides :-)

Comment: You could always use another call for the outer grid and set this to 0px margin.